# How to replace this string with regex and PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

Need some help with regex. I need to replace all instances with this:

```
padding-top: UNKNOWN VALUE;
```

**Input Could be:**

```
padding-top: 125.707%
...
padding-top: 80px
... 
padding-top: 21em
...
```

How do I do it using the `regexp_replace` of `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: You really should show us what you tried before asking. If you tried nothing, this means you're not working with us: you want us to work for you, for free. 

Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regexp_replace('padding-top: 80px;', ':[^;]*;', ': UNKNOWN VALUE;');
```

The regular expression: `:[^;]*;`
says: match any string beginning with a ":", followed by zero or more characters that are not ";", followed by ";".